# List View Inline Edit Errors not Showing up in the Popup

Tags: list-view, popup

I have a trigger validation in Case which is working fine. When I'm in the Case list view and trying inline edit even though the validation works fine, the failed/ success records are not showing up in the pop-up.
Has anyone experienced this or any workaround?
.
[image]

Comment: Can you **[edit]** your post to include an actual question?

Comment: It's already there as I feel - inline edit response popup doesn't contain any record; and to know if anyone have experienced this and workarounds if any. I've edited a little to post anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved after allowing popups from the browser(chrome). Not sure why it's not working when opening the popup by clicking on the popup link.

[image: popup working]